# How to merge two excel sheets in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I have an excel sheet with two sheets: Column, Metadata.

The data within the Column sheet is:

| No of Column | No of Row |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 5 |

The data within the Metadata sheet is:

| Name. | Data Type | Non Null Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID | int64 | 5 |
| Name | object | 5 |
| Age | int64 | 5 |
| Salary | float | 5 |

I want to merge these two sheets into one using pandas

After merge I want the output to be:

| Name. | Data Type | Non Null Values | Number of Columns | Number of Rows |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID | int64 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| Name | object | 5 |  |  |
| Age | int64 | 5 |  |  |
| Salary | float | 5 |  |  |

Comment: `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`

Comment: These are two sheets of same excel file

Comment: I provided a pandas solution as you tagged pandas. Import the two sheets as DataFrames, `concat`, save to new sheet. If you don't know how to import the data from excel then you need to focus your question a bit more.